# How to create procedure hsqldb liquibase with spring unit test

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, liquibase, hsqldb

I have a procedure, namely **check_customer_valid**.
In production, I've already added it into dbchangelog file as below:

```
<createProcedure catalogName="check_customer_valid"
                         dbms="postgresql"
                         encoding="utf8"
                         procedureName="check_customer_valid"
                         relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                         schemaName="public">
....
```

But when I run unit test in spring, it throws error "user lacks privilege or object not found: CHECK_CUSTOMER_VALID" because I am using **hsqldb** in the test environment, while production db is postgres.
I tried to update dbms="postgresql,hsqldb" in above config, however it throws simple syntax "Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: OR". Therefore, I have to add a new changeSet for test env only to declare this procedure.
However the problem is that procedure in HSQL require INOUT parameters, but in postgres it isn't.
My change set for test env is

```
<changeSet id="sonny add procedure for testing" author="sonny">
        <createProcedure catalogName="check_customer_valid"
                         dbms="hsqldb"
                         encoding="utf8"
                         procedureName="check_customer_valid"
                         relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                         schemaName="public">
            CREATE PROCEDURE CHECK_CUSTOMER_VALID(IN customerName VARCHAR(50), IN customerCity VARCHAR(50), INOUT result BOOLEAN)
            MODIFIES SQL DATA
            BEGIN ATOMIC
                SET result = true;
            END
        </createProcedure>
    </changeSet>
```

The error is still the same. **user lacks privilege or object not found: CHECK_CUSTOMER_VALID"**

Comment: I believe testing changesets on HSQL for a Postgres Production database is a dangerous strategy.  The sql is not the same, and honestly I would never trust my local testing on HSQL would translate to a successful prod deploy.  Why not setup a postgres docker environment?  Here's an example doing it with mysql: https://www.liquibase.org/setting-up-environment-liquibase-mssql-using-docker. You can just change the docker command to: 
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change in memory DB to Postgres for unit testing. It's the rule of our projects.

Comment: The procedure requires an OUT parameter for the boolean result. You shouldn't use INOUT because you are not providing a value for this parameter. It should use READS SQL DATA, instead of MODIFIES SQL DATA because it is not going to change any existing data in the database.